# iOS get app icon from app name

Tags: ios, icons, app-store

Is there a way to get the icon of an app just from the name? I know there is a way to grab the icon if you have the app ID but all I have is the app names. Or conversely can you get the app ID from the name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you need to check out the [iTunes API](https://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html).

Check out their example on Yelp:

https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=yelp&country=us&entity=software

The artwork images are found in two sizes under the keys `artworkUrl60` & `artworkUrl512`.