# How to get app icon from app name in android and iOS?

Tags: android, ios, google-play, icons, playback

Is there any API available to get the app icon from app name?

I know android has capability to read the installed apps but I want app icon which may not be installed on the users phone(Android).

```
try {
  val img = view.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.img)
  val icon = context.packageManager.getApplicationIcon("com.instagram.android")
  img.setImageDrawable(icon)
} catch (e : PackageManager.NameNotFoundException) {
  e.printStackTrace()
}
```

Also from below link iOS provides list but it has lot of apps other than exact name. E.g - "Youtube" as app name

[iOS get app icon from app name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26639656/ios-get-app-icon-from-app-name)

Is there any API where I can pass the app name like "Youtube", "Instagram" and get the app icon so that I can show that in my application.

Comment: There is no such API and I would not recommend to rely on an app icon of another app. You should use some third party icon or just a text in my opinion.

Comment: Thank you Nico. My use case needs app icon to be shown.